# Safari: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 ()

Tags: safari, resources, load

I have a problem accessing CSS found in a different domain from safari using imac, ipad, iphone. The error is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 ().

Searching I found Billi's answer [http2: The 421 Misdirected Request Status Code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785803/http2-the-421-misdirected-request-status-code-example/66712115#66712115)

I think I have the scenario that Billi mentions, I'll explain, I have a hosting where I have two domains hosted, domain 1: mysite.com/admin, and domain 2: mycompany.com/global/resources, on my site I am going to bring the css files to domain 2, but in safari I have an error, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 ()", as I said, this only happens in safari with imac, ipone and ipad, in windows and in chrome everything works fine, do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Can it be fixed from the .htaccess?

I have even try with this code in .htaccess and I got the same error.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
```

Comment: did you find the fix?